# heroku remote messess up github desktop

Tags: git, heroku, github

I use the github desktop app for windows to manage my project.
I have my project deployed to heroku.

When I have only one remote in the git project (origin) the github remote, the github desktop app works correctly.

when I add a heroku remote using the heroku toolbelt like so:

```
heroku git:remote -a [app-name]
```

I open github desktop I see no changes or history. I can see my branches but no details of the changes within the branch and the only option I have is the publish the branch again.

removing the heroku remote with

```
git remote rm heroku
```

solves the problem and my github desktop app works properly.

How can I get the heroku remote to play nice with the github desktop app?